# moving averages in a matrix - window out of bounds

Tags: r, moving-average

I have a simple matrix:

```
x <- seq (1:100)
matrix_A = matrix(x, ncol = 10)
matrix_A
```

I want to average all the values with a running window of size 3 x 3

Simple function to do that:

```
running_window_v1 <- function(mat.temp){

  #Create an empty matrix to store calculations in it
  mat.temp1=matrix(NA,ncol = ncol(mat.temp), nrow = nrow(mat.temp))

  for (i in (1 : (nrow(mat.temp)))){
    for (j in (1 : (ncol(mat.temp)))){
      mat.temp1[i,j] = mean (mat.temp[i - 1, j - 1],
        mat.temp[i - 1, j],
        mat.temp[i- 1, j + 1],
        mat.temp[i, j - 1],
        mat.temp[i, j],
        mat.temp[i, j + 1],
        mat.temp[i + 1, j - 1],
        mat.temp[i + 1, j], 
        mat.temp[i +1, j + 1])

    }
  }
  return(mat.temp1)
}

running_window_v1(matrix_A)
```

The problem with this script is obvious, I get error, because when (e.g.) `i = 1`, `j = 1`, I am calling values which does not exist in matrix `matrix_A[- 1, - 1]`. So, function would work only if I change it in the following way:

```
running_window_v2 <- function(mat.temp){

  #Create an empty matrix to store calculations in it
  mat.temp1=matrix(NA,ncol = ncol(mat.temp), nrow = nrow(mat.temp))

  for (i in (2 : (nrow(mat.temp)-1))){
    for (j in (2 : (ncol(mat.temp)-1))){
      mat.temp1[i,j] = mean (mat.temp[i - 1, j - 1],
                              mat.temp[i - 1, j],
                              mat.temp[i- 1, j + 1],
                              mat.temp[i, j - 1],
                              mat.temp[i, j],
                              mat.temp[i, j + 1],
                              mat.temp[i + 1, j - 1],
                              mat.temp[i + 1, j], 
                              mat.temp[i +1, j + 1])

    }
  }
  return(mat.temp1)
}


> running_window_v2(matrix_A)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [2,]   NA    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71    NA
 [3,]   NA    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72    NA
 [4,]   NA    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73    NA
 [5,]   NA    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74    NA
 [6,]   NA    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75    NA
 [7,]   NA    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76    NA
 [8,]   NA    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77    NA
 [9,]   NA    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78    NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

For my work, it is really important that I do not lose the information and I need to average also the edges (of course, using less numbers). Do you have any suggestions, how I could modify function `running_window_v1` to work fine for me? 
I understand I could write additional conditions for each possible edge, but I am looking for more elegant condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following within each loop (rather than listing all the elements individually, it is easier to use ranges for the indices here)

```
mat.temp1[i,j] = mean(mat.temp[max(1,i-1):min(nrow(mat.temp),i+1),
                               max(1,j-1):min(ncol(mat.temp),j+1)])
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Thank you.